# Is it possible to have separate pages for product details and product order forms?

Tags: magento-1.8, product, orders

I am trying to create a store that has a product details page that is separate from the order form. I want customers to view the product details before being able to order the product. After they visit the product details page, I want customers to click an "Order Now" button which takes them to an order form.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

**Product Details:**
http://www.zennioptical.com/270124-plastic-full-rim-frame.html

**Product Order Form:**
http://www.zennioptical.com/buy/270124-plastic-full-rim-frame.html?_windowid=new&curFaceId=sysface1670012

I have a lot of custom options that the customer must fill out for each order, and I need to have them on a separate page. Is this possible with Magento?

Answer (score 2):

Why not have form on the first page and hide it. When the customer then clicks the 'order now' button you display the form. Like in a different tab in the same page?

It saves you from having to create a controller action etc. that is almost identical to the original one. Especially when you have lots of custom product options.